# Using FireStore in Google Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to use FireStore in a Dataflow template with python.

I have done something like this:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
(p
| 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(sub).with_output_types(bytes)
| 'String to dictionary' >> beam.Map(firestore_update_multiple)
)
```

Is this the appropriate way to use it?

---

Extra information

```
def firestore_update_multiple(row):
    from google.cloud import firestore
    db = firestore.Client()
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'data').document(u'one')

    doc_ref.update({
        u'arrayExample': u'DataflowRunner',
        u'booleanExample': True
    })
```

Comment: Can you dive into how you're using the data incoming from pubsub to do updates in firestore?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,@Pablo. What I want with FireStore (I also have to test CloudSQL) is to use it like OLTP system, because I had tested BigQuery (OLAP) but is not the most suitable for my use case. Sometimes I would be able to batch the calls but in other case I have to do insert/update for each time I receive from pub/sub

Comment: Most streaming runners, including Dataflow, optimize bundles in streaming for short latency - so it is still a good idea to do batching, except that you will usually have very small bundles, thus small batches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general idea is correct, but you should look into allocating firestore connections less often, and batching your calls. Here is an example of a ParDo that should do this:

```
class FirestoreUpdateDoFn(beam.DoFn):

  def __init__(self, max_batch_size=500):
    self.element_batch = []
    self.max_batch_size = max_batch_size

  def start_bundle(self):
    self.db = firestore.Client()
    self.batch = db.batch()
    self.some_ref = db.collection(...)

  def process(self, row):
    self.element_batch.append(row)
    if len(self.element_batch) >= self.max_batch_size:
      self._flush_updates()

  def finish_bundle(self):
    self._flush_updates()
    self.db.close()

  def _flush_updates(self):
    for elm in self.element_batch:
      self.batch.update(...)
    batch.commit()
```

This should allow you to do fewer round-trip calls to Firestore, and make your pipeline faster. You'd then do something like so:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    (p
     | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(sub)
                              .with_output_types(bytes)
     | 'String to dictionary' >> beam.ParDo(FirestoreUpdateDoFn())
    )
```

Check out:

- [Firestore Documentation on Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)
- [PyDoc with Batches API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/batch.html)
- If you feel up for it, you can look at [the code of `PubSubUnboundedSink`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubUnboundedSink.java#L237), which does the same thing you're trying to do: Write efficiently to an external service while running on streaming

Comment: `def process(self, row):` thus the `row` a single document record like e.g. {username: 'test' } ? how can it do batch?