# Do we have a Firebase I/O connector for Apache Beam?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, connector

I tried looking for Firebase I/O connectors for Firebase but wasn't able to find one. Can someone please help me in doing so, or someone has a Firebase I/O connector with them to read and write my files, please help me with it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the following interesting link from the official `Google` documentation, showing a read and write example with `Beam` `Java` :

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/using-firestore-and-apache-beam-data-processing

```java
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

String collectionGroupId = "collection-group-name";
RpcQosOptions rpcQosOptions = RpcQosOptions.newBuilder()
    .withHintMaxNumWorkers(options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class)
    .getMaxNumWorkers())
    .build();

pipeline
       .apply(Create.of(collectionGroupId))
       .apply(new CreatePartitionQueryRequest(rpcQosOptions.getHintMaxNumWorkers()))
       .apply(FirestoreIO.v1().read().partitionQuery().withNameOnlyQuery().build())
       .apply(FirestoreIO.v1().read().runQuery().build())
       .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(
           (runQueryResponse) -> runQueryResponse.getDocument().getName())
       )
       .apply(ParDo.of(new CreateDeleteOperation()))
       .apply("shuffle writes", Reshuffle.viaRandomKey())
       .apply(
               FirestoreIO.v1().write()
                       .batchWrite()
                       .withRpcQosOptions(rpcQosOptions)
                       .build()
       );

pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

The link to the Javadoc :

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.41.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/firestore/FirestoreIO.html

You can also check this link showing an example of `write` with `FirestoreIO` :

[Add document to Firestore from Beam with auto generated ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163275/add-document-to-firestore-from-beam-with-auto-generated-id)

For `Python`, I think there is no open source `IO` now on `Beam`, but you can use the `Firestore` client in a `ParDo` and `DoFn`, here a link showing an example :

[Using FireStore in Google Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764533/using-firestore-in-google-dataflow)

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Apache Beam official website](https://beam.apache.org/)

Find `Documentation` in the header.

Inside you'll see `I/O Connectors`, click on it: [I/O Connectors](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/).

Find `Firestore IO` in the list, then read [its Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.41.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/firestore/FirestoreV1.html).

Or maybe you need `Datastore IO` (for older versions I guess), [here's the Javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.41.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.html).

Please note that [you need to choose the data base](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) you're using.

Comment: I still can't find any connector for Firebase, firestore connector is already there but my motive was to write data from firestore.